# How to fix the following Read1 instance?

Tags: parsing, haskell, typeclass

Consider the following program.

```hs
import Data.Functor.Classes
import Control.Monad.Identity

readsNullaryWith :: String -> t -> String -> ReadS t
readsNullaryWith name cons kw s = [(cons, s) | kw == name]

data ListM m a = Cons a (MList m a) | Null
type MList m a = m (ListM m a)

instance Read1 m => Read1 (ListM m) where
    liftReadsPrec rp rl = readsData $
        readsBinaryWith rp (liftReadsPrec rp' rl') "Cons" Cons <>
        readsNullaryWith "Null" Null where
            rp' = liftReadsPrec rp rl
            rl' = liftReadList rp rl

instance Show1 m => Show1 (ListM m) where
    liftShowsPrec sp sl d (Cons x xs) =
        showsBinaryWith sp (liftShowsPrec sp' sl') "Cons" d x xs where
            sp' = liftShowsPrec sp sl
            sl' = liftShowList sp sl
    liftShowsPrec _ _ _ Null =
        showString "Null"

instance (Read1 m, Read a) => Read (ListM m a) where readsPrec = readsPrec1
instance (Show1 m, Show a) => Show (ListM m a) where showsPrec = showsPrec1

main :: IO ()
main = do
    print (read "Identity (Null)" :: MList Identity Int)
    print (read "Identity Null" :: MList Identity Int) -- Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

I defined the `Read` and `Show` instances for `ListM m a`. Both of them type check. The expression `read "Identity (Null)" :: MList Identity Int` works as expected. However, the expression `read "Identity Null" :: MList Identity Int` throws a parse exception. How do I fix this `Read1` instance so that it doesn't require parentheses around nullary constructors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the program.

```hs
import Data.Functor.Classes
import Control.Monad.Identity

readsNullaryWith :: String -> t -> ReadS t
readsNullaryWith name cons s = [(cons, t) | (kw, t) <- lex s, kw == name]

data ListM m a = Cons a (MList m a) | Null
type MList m a = m (ListM m a)

instance Read1 m => Read1 (ListM m) where
    liftReadsPrec rp rl =
        readsData (readsBinaryWith rp (liftReadsPrec rp' rl') "Cons" Cons) <>
        const (readParen False $ readsNullaryWith "Null" Null) where
            rp' = liftReadsPrec rp rl
            rl' = liftReadList rp rl

instance Show1 m => Show1 (ListM m) where
    liftShowsPrec sp sl d (Cons x xs) =
        showsBinaryWith sp (liftShowsPrec sp' sl') "Cons" d x xs where
            sp' = liftShowsPrec sp sl
            sl' = liftShowList sp sl
    liftShowsPrec _ _ _ Null =
        showString "Null"

instance (Read1 m, Read a) => Read (ListM m a) where readsPrec = readsPrec1
instance (Show1 m, Show a) => Show (ListM m a) where showsPrec = showsPrec1

main :: IO ()
main = do
    print (read "Identity (Null)" :: MList Identity Int)
    print (read "Identity Null" :: MList Identity Int)
```

If the `readsData` parser fails then we try to match the nullary constructor with **optional** parens.